# Why isn't my file being opened?

Tags: java, file

The file is in the root directory of where my source code is. Also is having a number appened to the end of the path variable going to mess things up or how would you do that?

There are 10 files to choose from and they all have similar names but end with a different number. So I was thinking of having the default path variable and then append the number to it and then doing File nameFile = new File(path + year + ".txt")

Any idea why it's not picking it up?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nameRanker {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int skip = 0;
    int rank = 0;
    int year = 0;
    char gender = '0';
    String name = "";
    String compareName = "";
    Boolean found = false;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the year: ");  //try to catch mismatched input here (0-10)
    try { year = input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.print("\nEnter the gender: ");  //try to catch mismatched input here (M or F)
    gender = input.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("\nEnter the name: ");   //try to catch mismatched input here (no #)
    name = input.next();
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.err.println("Entered value does not match expected value. \n(Year must be integer, gender M or F, and name must be a string.)");
    }

    String path = "\\BabynamesrankingFiles\\Babynamesranking";
    File nameFile = new File(path + year + ".txt");   //throws IOexception if not found 
    //Scanner readFile = null;

    try (Scanner readFile = new Scanner(nameFile)){
    //readFile = new Scanner(nameFile);
    if(nameFile.canRead()){ //if the file is readable
        while(readFile.hasNext() && !found){    //while data in file

            if(gender == 'M'){      //if male only parse first two values 
                rank = readFile.nextInt();      //store rank
                compareName = readFile.next();      //grab name to compare
                found = (compareName == name) ? true : false;  //if name found break while loop
            }

            if(gender == 'F'){
                rank = readFile.nextInt();      //store the rank
                compareName = readFile.next();   //store the boy name
                skip = readFile.nextInt();      //store the total names value even though unused
                compareName = readFile.next();  //store the girl name to compare
                found = (compareName == name) ? true : false;  //if name found break while loop
            }
        } //end while loop

        if(!found){             //if name not found 
            System.out.println("The name " + name + "is not ranked in year " + year);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The name " + name + " is ranked " + rank + " in the year " + year);
        }
      }
    }

    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error could not open file, check file path."); 
    }

    finally {   
    input.close();          //close scanner
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You say the files are in the root directory of the source, but according to your code, they are in a subdirectory called BabynamesrankingFiles. Which one is it?

Comment: Clear up your vague "default path variable" and "root directory of where my source code" is. Thats gibberish to everyone who cannot look at the filesystem of your computer. And most likely you're missing that the *source code* path plays no role when actually running your program. There is only *one* root directory per windows-drive and thats where a path starting with a \ begins; thats presumably a very different location than what you vaguely describe.